# Hide multiple input fields conditionally

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have incident report. If the user types in 3, 3 rows appear to describe each incident.

[image]

The two columns to the write of the page, "Employee" and "Opportunity (Patient)". I want neither of the fields to display if the "Affected Population" value in the row is selected to "--None---",

Only the employee field to display if "Affected Population" value in the row is set to "Employee",

etc

Here is the visualforce code for those Affected Population and two columns on the right

```
<!--Infection Incidents Section -->         
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Infection Incidents : {!InfectionCount}" columns="1" id="infecIncidentsec" showHeader="false"> 

<apex:pageBlockTable style="width:100%" value="{!Infections}" var="item" rendered="{!Infections.size > 0}">  

 <apex:column style="width:11%;" headerValue="Date of Incident">  
     <apex:inputField value="{!item.DateOfIncident__c}" required="true"/> 
 </apex:column> 

 <apex:column style="width:11%;" headerValue="Affected Population">  
     <apex:inputField value="{!item.Affected_Population__c}" required="true" onchange="showFields(this)" styleClass="affecPopulateList">
         <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="colEmp, colOpp"/>
     </apex:inputField>
 </apex:column>

 <apex:column style="width:11%;" headerValue="Infected on Admission">
             <apex:OutputPanel layout="block" styleClass="requiredInput infecInItem patient" >
                 <span>
                     <apex:OutputPanel styleClass="requiredBlock"/>
                     <apex:inputField value="{!item.Infection_Present_on_Admission__c}" styleClass="infecInInputItem patientinfecInInputItem infecRequired"/>
                     <div class="errorMsg" style="display:none">
                         <strong></strong>
                         You must enter a value.
                     </div>
                 </span>
             </apex:OutputPanel> 
 </apex:column>


 <apex:column style="width:11%"  headerValue="Employee" id="colEmp">  
             <apex:OutputPanel layout="block" styleClass="requiredInput infecInItem employee" >
                 <span>
                     <apex:OutputPanel styleClass="requiredBlock" />
                     <apex:inputField style="width:80%"  value="{!item.Employee__c}" styleClass="infecInInputItem employeeinfecInInputItem infecRequired" rendered="{!item.Affected_Population__c == 'Employee' }"/>
                     <div class="errorMsg" style="display:none">
                         <strong></strong>
                         You must enter a value.
                     </div>
                 </span>
             </apex:OutputPanel>                               
 </apex:column>

 <apex:column style="width:56%;" headerValue="Opportunity (Patient)" id="colOpp">  
             <apex:OutputPanel layout="block" styleClass="requiredInput infecInItem patient" >
                 <span>
                     <apex:OutputPanel styleClass="requiredBlock"/>
                     <apex:inputField style="width:15%" value="{!item.Opportunity__c}" styleclass="infecInInputItem patientinfecInInputItem infecRequired" rendered="{!item.Affected_Population__c != '' }"/>
                     <div class="errorMsg" style="display:none">
                         <strong></strong>
                         You must enter a value.
                     </div> 
                 </span>
             </apex:OutputPanel>                               
 </apex:column>
```

I know there is a rendered property for the apex:column component, but my if statement doesn't appear to be working

```
rendered="{! If(item.Affected_Population__C == "Employee",true,false) }"
```

Comment: Probably would be a lot more straightforward if you move the row layout to a component.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand. Still new to VF, only worked on lightning stuff

Comment: You may be able to use the `<apex:component>` [tag](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_component.htm) to make the logic more modular. Just a thought.

Comment: did you try to move the rendered to the outputpanel instead of the apex:column ? Also try {!item.Affected_Population__C == "Employee"} Way more simple!

Comment: I tried using rendered in outputPanel. No luck

Answer (score 1):

Your rendered args needs to be on the input fields. Also, you haven't shown us the onchange args in the 'Affected Population' field.

So I made some assumptions and wrote this (using Contact object, you can change to suit...)

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="Test1" sidebar="true" showHeader="true">
    <apex:form >

    <apex:pageBlock >
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" showHeader="false">

            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!contacts}" var="o">

                <apex:column headerValue="Date of Incident">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!o.Date_of_Incident__c}" />
                </apex:column>

                <apex:column  headerValue="Affected Population" >
                    <apex:inputField value="{!o.Affected_Population__c}">
                        <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="colEmp,colOpp" />
                    </apex:inputField>
                </apex:column>

                <apex:column headerValue="Infected on Admission" >
                    <apex:inputField value="{!o.Infected_on_Admission__c}" />
                </apex:column>

                <apex:column headerValue="Employee" id="colEmp">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!o.Employee__c}" rendered="{!o.Affected_Population__c == 'Employee'}" />
                </apex:column>

                <apex:column headerValue="Opportunity (Patient)" id="colOpp">
                    <apex:inputField value="{!o.Opportunity_Patient__c}" rendered="{!o.Affected_Population__c != ''}" />
                </apex:column>

            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>

    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Note how the Affected Population input field has the child tag 'actionSupport'. This is where we can define an onchange and rerender events.

When that picklist changes, VF will rerender (recalc and redisplay) the two columns Employee and Opportunity (Patient).

HTH.

Comment: I appreciate you answer, but it doesn't appear to work for me. I'll keep tinkering and see if I'm doing something wrong

Comment: I updated my post with the Affected Population code, including your code recommendation

Comment: The fields are not displaying at all using your method. It appears the rerender isn't working on the apex:actionSupport

Comment: did you put an id arg in the two columns? The rerender args are references tag ids.

<apex:column headerValue="Employee" id="colEmp">
<apex:column headerValue="Opportunity (Patient)" id="colOpp">

If it's not this, can you paste your VF page into a pastebin or something? Difficult to debug in snippets. I did test the above code I posted, so it does work :)

Comment: My code in my post is updated to with your solution. Still not working, but maybe you can see what I'm doing wrong.